# Mock spring security roles through the header with JWT

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

Is possible to make a very simple JWT example with Spring Security.

I want to illustrate how roles can be used, without setting up the all of the spring security.

Basically I want to use postman with a jwt token which contain the roles. I don't want to setup user login. Is possible?

Comment: The token is the login. Nonentheless you still need to setup Spring Security else it won't work. You need a JwtFilter that decodes the token and does the login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can create JWTFilter class and extends GenericFilterBean then
>   override to doFilter.You can resolve jwt token in this method and jwt
>   is valid then you can get claim
>
> List roles =
>   Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(secretKey).parseClaimsJws(Jwt).getClaims("roles");

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    try {
        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
        String jwt = resolveToken(httpServletRequest);
        if (StringUtils.hasText(jwt)) {
            if (this.tokenProvider.validateToken(jwt)) {

            }
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
    }catch(Exception ex){
        handleException((HttpServletResponse) servletResponse,ex);
    }
}

private String resolveToken(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String bearerToken = request.getHeader(JWTConfigurer.AUTHENTICATION_HEADER);
    if (StringUtils.hasText(bearerToken) && bearerToken.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
        String jwt = bearerToken.substring(7, bearerToken.length());
        return jwt;
    }

    String jwt = request.getParameter(JWTConfigurer.AUTHENTICATION_TOKEN);
    if (StringUtils.hasText(jwt)) {
        return jwt;
    }
    return null;
}
```